# UnfoldingMaps add MarkerList after initialization

Tags: java, processing

I'm writing an application where I show markers on a map using the library Unfolding Maps.
The application lets the user choose a year and depending on that value other markers are shown. This works perfect, but when the user selects another year I can't seem to get the other markers shown.

I've tried to completely renew the map but after that first time it doesn't redraw a map.

Besides that I've tried to add a MarkerManager to the map but then I get errors of OpenGL.

setup function:

```
   public void setup() {

    /*
     * Provincies, set zoom to 10
     */

    size(1000, 800, OPENGL);


    this.map = new UnfoldingMap(this, new Microsoft.RoadProvider());

    map.zoomAndPanTo(belgie, 8);
    map.setPanningRestriction(belgie, 1);
    map.setZoomRange(8, 8);

drawOtherMarker();
    //map.getMarkerManager(markerRemarck.get(keyM)).enableDrawing();

    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
}
```

function that creates the MarkerManager and adds it to the map

```
    private void createMarkers(ArrayList<double[]> dataMarker) {
    float size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ListIterator<double[]> dataIt = dataMarker.listIterator();
    ArrayList<SimplePointMarker> markList = new ArrayList<SimplePointMarker>();

    while (dataIt.hasNext()) {
        double[] element = dataIt.next();
        SimplePointMarker point = new SimplePointMarker(new Location(
                element[0], element[1]));

        if (element[2] > 1000)
            size = 120;
        else if (element[2] > 100)
            size = 60;
        else if (element[2] > 10)
            size = 30;
        else
            size = 20;

        point.setRadius(size);

        point.setColor(color(64,64,64,100));

        point.setStrokeColor(color(178,34,34));
        point.setStrokeWeight(30);

        point.setStrokeWeight(0);
        point.setId(Integer.toString(i++));
        markList.add(point);
    }
    MarkerManager man = new MarkerManager(markList);
    map.addMarkerManager(man);
    }
```

When the map is drawn and another set of markers must be drawn the following function is called:

```
    public void drawOtherMarker(){
    if(!markerRemarck.containsKey(keyM)){
        markerRemarck.put(keyM, totalMark++);
        createMarkers(dataMarkerProvince);

    }
    if(dataMarkerTown != null){
        markerRemarck.put(keyM + "city", totalMark++);
        createMarkers(dataMarkerTown);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < totalMark;++i)
        map.getMarkerManager(i).disableDrawing();


  map.getMarkerManager(markerRemarck.get(keyM)).enableDrawing();
    }
```

another function brings in the data required to make the markers. I just don't seem to manage to add a MarkerManager after the first draw.

**EDIT** 
This map is placed inside a JPanel. And the years are choosen with the help of a JComboBox. Once a year is chosen the "dataMarker" variable containing the information for creating markers is updated

thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: If your markers are independent (i.e. no marker should be visible in multiple views, e.g. can only have one year per marker) I'd suggest creating both marker managers before drawing, and then simply switching the marker manager on user interaction. This might be what you are already trying, but I don't see your draw() nor your UI methods. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @tnagel I was thinking about creating the marker up front but that would mean a lot of work. That's why I was wondering if there was another way. Like stopping the map without stopping my whole application(the map is placed inside a JPanel) or adding Markers later. But nothing else seems to work, so I think I'm going to create the markers up front.